# how to use jquery datatable plugin properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Below is my example code, but it's not working. Can someone please help me on how to use this  jquery datatable plugin? 
And can this datatable plugin used on sql result field table? Thanks

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> 
    </head>

    <body>
       <table id="example"  style="border:1px solid black;">   
            <thead>


   <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>         
                <th>Column 2</th>          
                <th>etc</th>       
            </tr>   
        </thead>

        <tbody> 
            <tr>       
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>   
                <td>etc</td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td> 
                <td>etc</td>  
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td> 
                <td>etc</td>  
           </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable();
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What should it be doing that it's not?

Comment: It is showing only basic html yable, not datatable

Answer (score 4):

From the docs: https://datatables.net/manual/installation

> For DataTables to be able to enhance an HTML table, the table must be
>   valid, well formatted HTML, with a header (thead) and a body (tbody).
>   An optional footer (tfoot) can also be used.

Try adding a `thead` to your table with the correct number of columns.

It should look like this, but with however rows and columns you need, and your `td`'s filled with your content.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Added thead and tbody in table. still showing basic html table. Please help

Comment: Using your same code/html, it works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/ay8pwcp5/2/

Comment: I am using this in WordPress. I am fetching the data from sql server and populating in html table. For this I need a datatable but it just not working. Do I need to add any jquery into my website folder?

Comment: I don't know WordPress, but you need 3 files to make this work. jquery.js, datatables.js, and datatables.css, that's all.