# datatables compatible with jquery 1.12?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying out DataTables, and I have a similar issue to this user: 
[how to use jquery datatable plugin properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708850/how-to-use-jquery-datatable-plugin-properly).

When I try their code I actually have a proper DataTable. But if I use the latest versions of [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) and [DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/installation), I only have a basic HTML table.

Are there some issues of compatibility between DataTables and jQuery?

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.19/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.19/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>etc</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        <td>etc</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
  });
</script>

</html>
```

**EDIT** : Thanks to Rory McCrossan, the links to datatables that I copy-pasted were indeed broken!

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 1.x has known security issues and is beyond End Of Life so it does not get security updates. **Do not use jQuery 1.x**

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet. The error (which would have been displayed in the console) is now clear to see.

Comment: Iv'e changed the order of scripts, and I still have a problem.

Comment: 1) Put your `script` tag *inside* the `body` 2) Your CDN link to datatables.min.js is broken. The latter is the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of your Js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.19/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Jquery needs to be initialized first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.19/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem - you're importing **jQuery DataTables** *before* you're importing **jQuery** itself. Change your script loading order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.19/datatables.min.js"></script>
```